# MongoDB + Mongo-Express docker-compose causing MongoError: Authentication failed

Tags: mongodb, docker

I've been on this issue for hours now and I really don't know what else to do (and all the research I did didn't provide any solution unfortunately). So I'm asking if anyone can think of an answer why this is not working:

I run a **docker-compose file with mongo and mongo-express images**. Using the default code provided [here](https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo/) didnt work ( mongo-express stopped with exit code 1) so I tried tons of configurations leaving me with the docker-compose file below ( that actually works to the degree that mongo-express gets started and shows

***Databases:*   *admin***

***Server Status:*
*Turn on admin in config.js to view server stats!***

displayed in the GUI). But from there nothing works. The console shows the problem:

```
mongoviewer_1  | Database connected
database_1     | 2018-08-22T09:15:27.743+0000 I ACCESS   [conn2] SASL SCRAM-SHA-1 authentication failed for admin on admin from client; UserNotFound: Could not find user admin@admin

mongoviewer_1  | unable to list databases
mongoviewer_1  | { MongoError: command listDatabases requires authentication
mongoviewer_1  |     at Function.MongoError.create (/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/error.js:31:11)
mongoviewer_1  |     at /node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:483:72
mongoviewer_1  |     at authenticateStragglers (/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:429:16)
mongoviewer_1  |     at Connection.messageHandler (/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:463:5)
mongoviewer_1  |     at Socket.<anonymous> (/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connection.js:319:22)
mongoviewer_1  |     at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
mongoviewer_1  |     at Socket.emit (events.js:211:7)
mongoviewer_1  |     at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:263:12)
mongoviewer_1  |     at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:250:11)
mongoviewer_1  |     at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:208:10)
mongoviewer_1  |   name: 'MongoError',
mongoviewer_1  |   message: 'command listDatabases requires authentication',
mongoviewer_1  |   ok: 0,
mongoviewer_1  |   errmsg: 'command listDatabases requires authentication',
mongoviewer_1  |   code: 13,
mongoviewer_1  |   codeName: 'Unauthorized' }
```

The docker-compose looks like follows:

```
  database:
    image: mongo:latest
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: admin
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
      MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE: dockerdb
    ports:
    - "27017:27017"
  mongoviewer:
    image: mongo-express
    environment:
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_SERVER: database
      ME_CONFIG_BASICAUTH_USERNAME: ""
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_AUTH_DATABASE: admin
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_AUTH_USERNAME: admin
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_AUTH_PASSWORD: password
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME: admin
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD: password
    ports:
    - "8081:8081"
    links:
    - database
    depends_on:
    - database
```

That's the current version I was trying and I tried so many other configurations but nothing fixed the auth problem.

If anyone has an answer or at least an idea on what to do I'd be extremely thankfull!

Answer (score 2):

Essentially there are two states when you are configuring your `docker-compose.yaml`. I am no expert but this solution resolved this issue for me.

1. **No Authentication Required**

By default when you're running `mongo` instance, it requires authentication to access the databases since you are specifying both `MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME` and `MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD`.

You can access the databases in `mongo` by removing both of the keys.

2. **Authentication Required**

According to [mongo-express documentation](https://github.com/mongo-express/mongo-express#usage-docker), by default the `ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ENABLE_ADMIN` key is `false` making your mongo-express application will not try for any authentication and directly connect to your `mongo` instance (thus producing the `Authentication failed` error).

You will need to enable the `ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ENABLE_ADMIN` key by changing it to true. Remember to stringify the "true" in your `docker-compose.yaml`.

Ensure the `ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME` and `ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD` keys match `MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME` and `MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD` keys respectively.

Answer (score 1):

When we login using localhost:8081 it asks username and password , when we give declared username and pwd it fails. rather pls execute docker logs containerID/containerName  and see basic credentials printed. Kindly use the mentioned credentials , admin:pass. Hope it solves the error
[Docker Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AmHXU.png)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the info on the docker file, if MongoDB runs on a container named "database", it can be accessed from mongo-express using:

```
 docker run -it --rm \
--network web_default \
--name mongo-express \
-p 8081:8081 \
-e ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_SERVER=database \
-e ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME= admin \
-e ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD=password \
mongo-express
```

For reference check the [mongo-express Docu on dockerhub](https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo-express)

Note: that in case you want to access a specific database with a user credentials:

```
docker run -it --rm \
--network web_default \
--name mongo-express \
-p 8081:8081 \
-e ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_SERVER= database \
-e ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_AUTH_DATABASE= dockerdb \
-e ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ENABLE_ADMIN=false \
-e ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_AUTH_USERNAME=admin \
-e ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_AUTH_PASSWORD=password \
mongo-express
```